# UICollectionViewController - unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implemented a Collection View controller and am massively failing... How do I get rid of this unwrapping error ? It occurs when I create my collectionView cell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Here is the code.

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = picturesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell

    if let photoObject = pictureObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? PictureElement {

        let title = photoObject.title ?? "" // if photoObject.title == nil, then we return an empty string

        let timeStampDateObject = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(photoObject.timeStamp))
        let timeStampDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(timeStampDateObject)

        let author = photoObject.author ?? ""

        let issueNumber = photoObject.issueNumber ?? ""
        let volumeNumber = photoObject.volumeNumber ?? ""

        let nodeID = photoObject.nodeID ?? 0

        let imageURL = photoObject.imageURL ?? ""

        cell!.request?.cancel()

        // Using image cache system to make sure the table view works even when rapidly scrolling down the screen.
        if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {

            cell!.imageView.image = image

        } else {

            cell!.imageView.image = nil
            cell!.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).responseImage { response in
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    self.imageCache.setObject(response.result.value!, forKey: imageURL)
                    cell!.imageView.image = image

                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
}
    return cell!
```

}

Also, I already tried to use a guard-let statement and it didn't work. Here it is:

```
        guard let cell = picturesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell else {

        print("cell could not be initialized as PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell, hence it will be casted to another default UICollectionViewCell type")
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)


    }
```

Comment: Need more information can you post your error message.

Comment: That's really all I get. I haven't been able to figure out anything else. What do you think it could be (even if you're not sure) ?

Comment: Which line cause an error?

Comment: @t4nhpt According to my debugging, everything crashes as soon as I create the cell, on line 'let cell = picturesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell'. Even if I replace this with my "guard let" statement, the application still crashes. So the problem is clearly with the cell, or perhaps more specifically with its properties (labels, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a storyboard...

1. Make sure you set the reuse identifier for the cell in the storyboard to match the value of PhotoBrowserCellIdentifier.
2. Make sure you set the class for the cell in the storyboard to PhotoBrowserCollectionViewCell.

Comment: Yeah I already have that set up. Any other possible solutions ?

Comment: A last possible one, did you connect the IBOutlet to your `picturesCollectionView`? Trying to use `po` command and print any value at the crashed line to view what's nil variable.